# Can't get an Internet connection on VmWare

Tags: vmware-server, ethernet

I'm running openSuse 11.1 on VmWare and I can't get on internet.

I'm at home, no ports blocked or anything, I've tried every single ethernet option, nothing works.

Can anybody point me at settings I might be missing?

Comment: Can you get to anything on the local network ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What flavour of VMWare?  Server, ESX Server, workstation..?

Try checking the VM's settings to check that the network card's (a) connected, and (b) connected to the right network if you've got more than one.  That's the most common mistake I make.

Answer (score 0):

A little more information would be needed to help here, but here are some starting points:

1) in the VM, is it seeing the interface and bringing it up?

2) If it is up, is it acquiring an IP?

3) If it has an IP is able to ping its gateway? Is it able to ping a public internet IP? Is it able to ping a domain on the internet(to test dns)?

Answer (score 0):

What version of VMWare and how is your system connected to the internet/network?  VMWare's free Virtual Server doesn't support wireless network cards, at least it didn't a number of months ago, I don't know if the current version supports them now.

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since using VMWare but here are some further questions if you are using Workstation (I dont have ESX experience):

1. Have you installed the VMWare tools?
2. Is the NIC connected & enabled in the VM Settings>
3. Can you ping 127.0.0.1 and get a response? (This tests the TCP/IP suite)
4. Can you run ifconfig eth0 (first Virtual NIC) and get any information? (This ensures that the NIC modules have been loaded)

Without much more information I would assume you have not loaded the VMTools into the OS, but I cannot be sure without further information from yourself.